# Git log earlier than branch point

Tags: git, git-branch

My repository basically looks like this:

```
-- X -- A -- B -- C -- D -- F  (master) 
          \     /   \     /
           \   /     \   /
             G -- H -- I -- J  (deployment-branch-1)
```

Usually, I am asked, what went into the deploy and what was not in. `Git log` on the branch only gives me the log down to the branch point "A"

From the example above, this would look like this:

```
$ git co deployment-branch-1
$ git log --oneline --decorate
J (HEAD, deployment-branch-1) branch commit
I branch commit
H branch commit
G branch commit
```

... but alas no commit line for A or earlier. I want to show log all the way from tip of branch INCLUDING commits made before the branch point. Like this:

```
J (HEAD, deployment-branch-1) branch commit
I branch commit
H branch commit
G branch commit
A (master) master commit
X master commit
```

So my question is, how do I show the longer log?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the entire log to be shown for a branch; not just the log from the branch point up to HEAD.  You might try using the `<source>..<target>` option as:

```
git log --oneline --decorate X..J
```

An example.  Here is the output of

```
   git log --oneline --graph --all

* 1eaa578 histogrammer
| * 9c7e745 Revert "Revert "Initial README""
| * 63a94ef Revert "Initial README"
| * 8c7f0ec Use ...; remove define-values, vector-copy, and case-lambda; a
|/  
* 18e6e26 Initial README
* 528c542 Add copyright notice based on the MIT License
...
```

I then checkout `9c7e745` (which is the head of a branch `foo`).  And then try `git log --oneline`.  You can see that it continues beyond the branch.

```
9c7e745 Revert "Revert "Initial README""
63a94ef Revert "Initial README"
8c7f0ec Use ...; remove define-values, vector-copy, and case-lambda; add f
18e6e26 Initial README
528c542 Add copyright notice based on the MIT License
...
```

My git version:

```
ebg@ebg(181)$ git --version
git version 1.7.9.6 (Apple Git-31.1)
```

and no difference with:

```
ebg@ebg(185)$ /usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 1.7.10.3
```

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't work. I tried `git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)`, which stops at "G" (the first unique commit after the branch point). Does it work for you?

Comment: See edits.  I see the entire log.  Note there are lots of options to limit the output of `git log` (see https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html).  Perhaps you have something installed that sets a default.  Try `git log --all`

Comment: No, `git log --all` is NOT what I want, since it will give me all commits on all branches. I only want the path from the current branch and back on master

Comment: I know that is not what you want; not sure why I suggested it at this point.  As you can see from my edits, after doing `git log --oneline --graph --all` to ensure that my branching structure is as expected, I did `git log --oneline` from a checked out branch and I saw all the branch history (including beyond the branch point).  Good luck.